# Put values in array that are not in another array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
test_idc = images(1:50:5000);
train_idc = images(...)
```

what would I put for the train_idc array that would include the 4900 values not used in test_idc array?

Comment: Take a look at `setdiff`, you can start with all indices 1:50000 and remove those indices you already used

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
% Sample data (54000 x 10)
data = rand(54000,10);
% Cross varidation (train: 70%, test: 30%)
cv = cvpartition(size(data,1),'HoldOut',0.3);
idx = cv.test;
% Separate to training and test data
dataTrain = data(~idx,:);
dataTest  = data(idx,:);
```

Credit: [link](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/377839-split-training-data-and-testing-data#answer_300781)